# Mysql connect two concat tables after processing

Tags: mysql, merge, procedure, concatenation

My goal is to present data from DOC_sql and MDT_sql in a table. Can not find a solution on how this linkage should be implemented.

The goal is to search through documents and present the documents based on  matching tags.

Input data

```
CALL SearthDocuments('\'Book\',\'Currency\'', 'en_ENG');
```

Code

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE SearthDocuments(IN VAR_TT_names VARCHAR(255), VAR_LANG_prefix CHAR(6))
BEGIN

SET @TT_sql = CONCAT('SELECT TAG_ID FROM TagTranslate WHERE TT_text IN (', VAR_TT_names, ')');
SET @DOC_ID_sql = CONCAT('SELECT DOC_ID FROM DocumentTag WHERE TAG_ID IN (', @TT_sql, ') GROUP BY DOC_ID HAVING COUNT(DOC_ID)');

SET @DOC_sql = CONCAT('SELECT * FROM VIEW_Document WHERE DOC_ID IN (', @DOC_ID_sql, ') AND LANG_prefix = "', VAR_LANG_prefix, '"' );
SET @MDT_sql = CONCAT('SELECT DOC_ID, count(*) as TAG_HITS FROM DocumentTag WHERE TAG_ID IN (', @TT_sql, ') GROUP BY DOC_ID HAVING COUNT(DOC_ID)');

-- SET @COM_sql = CONCAT('?')
-- PREPARE COM_stmt FROM @COM_sql;
-- EXECUTE COM_stmt;
-- DEALLOCATE PREPARE COM_stmt;
END
// DELIMITER ;
```

Both tables have the identifier DOC_ID

TABLE: DOC_sql

```
DOC_ID, DT_ID, DT_desc, DT_title, A_name, LANG_prefix
```

TABLE: MDT_sql

```
DOC_ID, TAG_HITS
```

Comment: wouldn't  it be nice if you could say what the tables look like

Comment: This is a weired function which creates sql statements with `concat` and tries to execute several cascaded sqls on two tables. What is the table structure, the data and what should be the output? Bottom-line: what is the basic task to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution for the problem. Working code.

```
DELIMITER //
    CREATE PROCEDURE SearthDocuments(IN VAR_TT_names VARCHAR(255), VAR_LANG_prefix CHAR(3))
    BEGIN

  SET @TT_sql = CONCAT('SELECT TAG_ID FROM TagTranslate WHERE TT_text IN (', VAR_TT_names, ')');
  SET @DOC_ID_sql = CONCAT('SELECT DOC_ID FROM DocumentTag WHERE TAG_ID IN (', @TT_sql, ') GROUP BY DOC_ID HAVING COUNT(DOC_ID)');

  SET @DOC_sql = CONCAT('SELECT * FROM VIEW_Document WHERE DOC_ID IN (', @DOC_ID_sql, ') AND LANG_prefix = ',VAR_LANG_prefix);
  SET @MDT_sql = CONCAT('SELECT DOC_ID, count(*) as TAG_HITS FROM DocumentTag WHERE TAG_ID IN (', @TT_sql, ') GROUP BY DOC_ID HAVING COUNT(DOC_ID)');

   SET @COM_sql = CONCAT('
       SELECT * FROM 
         (SELECT * FROM VIEW_Document WHERE DOC_ID IN (', @DOC_ID_sql, ') AND LANG_prefix = "',VAR_LANG_prefix,'") AS V_DOC
         LEFT JOIN 
         (SELECT DOC_ID, count(*) as TAG_HITS FROM DocumentTag WHERE TAG_ID IN (', @TT_sql ,') GROUP BY DOC_ID HAVING COUNT(DOC_ID)) as Searth
         on V_DOC.DOC_ID = Searth.DOC_ID ORDER BY TAG_HITS DESC;'
     );

     PREPARE COM_stmt FROM @COM_sql;
     EXECUTE COM_stmt;
     DEALLOCATE PREPARE COM_stmt;

END
// DELIMITER ;
```